# Google Contacts date format for birthdays, without the year, which date formats work?

Tags: google-calendar, google-contacts

For example, if you enter the **birthday in Google Contacts** as

> 13 May or May 13 or 13/5 or 1305 or 13.05

will the birthday flow through to Google Calendars?

Answer (score 7):

I'm using the new(er) Google Contacts. This is what I found in my tests. (Note that I'm using U.S. locale dates, i.e., mm/dd. Your results will likely depend on how dates are formatted in your locale.)

- `1 Nov` - Doesn't appear to be recognized as a date
- `1 November` - Doesn't appear to be recognized as a date
- `November 1` - Appeared on calendar
- `Nov 1` - Converted to "November 1" before saving contact. Appeared on calendar
- `1101` - Doesn't appear to be recognized as a date
- `11.01` - Doesn't appear to be recognized as a date
- `11/1` - Converted to "November 1" before saving contact. Appeared on calendar
- `11/01` - Converted to "November 1" before saving contact. Appeared on calendar
- `11-1` - Doesn't appear to be recognized as a date
- `11-01` - Doesn't appear to be recognized as a date

It seems to me that as long as Google Contacts can convert the date into the standard format for your locale, it will appear on your Google Calendar. If Google Contacts can't figure it out, then it won't. You'll need to do your own experimentation.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Using format   in english.
for example : June 1

and it's worked for me and synced to my Google Calendar.

Answer (score -3):

It's probably dependent on your configured locale, but in most cases "dd mmmmm YYYY" works, like "4 november 2016".

Comment: Yes, except the question is about birthdays without years.